# Where does Stylus output to?

Tags: css, stylus

For example, to see what parameters a function or mixin accept we use Stylus built-in function `p( )`.  `p(rgba)` should generate `inspect: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)`. I created a file `style.styl` with a single line `p(rgba)`. Compiled it, but the generated `.css` file is empty. Not that I am surprised, I mean I understand that this code doesn't generate any CSS. But where do I look for the output?

Should there be some kind of console or something? Or is it only used to pass some arguments within Stylus mixins and functions (that would be odd)? I'm running OS X and compile Stylus with free version of Prepros app. Maybe it has something to do with Node.js? I am not familiar with it yet, though I do know JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the output using the Terminal app. For that I had to install `node.js` first, after that I installed Stylus using Terminal by typing `nmp install -g stylus`, and finally I could able to compile any `.styl` file using the command `stylus` + the path to the `.styl` file. After the file compiled I was able to see the output I was looking for:

```
    inspect: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)
    compiled style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

This function outputs the info into STDIN through Node.js' `console.log` method. I don't know if there any kind of STDIN (maybe some log?) in Prepros.

Comment: I think the problem was that I didn't have `node.js` and `Stylus` installed on my system. Which is perfectly fine, if all you need is the generated `.css` file. So I installed those and compiled the `.styl` using Terminal and that allowed me to see all the messages from Stylus in the Terminal window. I haven't seen any console/log thing in Prepros, and I also tried CodeKit and it had some log, but it didn't have anything but the compilation logs. Thank you for answering!